# Run maven cucumber tests from IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I have a maven project, which run cucumber tests using JUnit runner.  I can use the following syntax from command line to run the tests:

```
mvn -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Sanity" test
```

This works perfectly fine when run from the console.  Now I'm trying to set up Maven runner configuration in IntelliJ IDEA to do the same - and I just can't get it to work.  According to the [IntelliJ documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-runner.html), I need to \-escape double quotes - so in the command line I specify `-Dcucumber.options=\'--tags @Sanity\' test`

Maven is executed - but produces this error message:

```
Unknown lifecycle phase "@Sanity""
```

It appears that the parameter is unescaped before being passed to maven. I then tried to putting the entire thing in quotes, specifying parameters as `'-Dcucumber.options=\"--tags @Sanity\"' test`. This results in the following error:

```
Unknown lifecycle phase "'-Dcucumber.options="--tags"
```

Again, I guess, something is with quoting/escaping.  I then tried these options: `"-Dcucumber.options='--tags @Sanity'" test` - this time maven goes through the compilation stage and seemingly attempts to run tests - but then fails with the following error:

```
Tests in error:
```

initializationError(com.mycompany.mypackage.MyRunner): Unknown option: --tags @Sanity

I tried all sorts of quoting/escaping/double-escaping/double-quoting/etc. - to no avail.

Again, running maven from command line works fine - I am specifically interested in setting it up as a runner configuration in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Try placing the lifecycle phase(test) before the cucumber options.

Comment: Tried that already - made no difference

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape space character: mvn "-Dcucumber.options=--tags\ @Sanity" test

Comment: Doesn't help - same error: `Unknown options: --tags\ `

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot with your run configuration?